# get row with max values in all columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting indices for data frame rows that have MAX value for named field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025051/extracting-indices-for-data-frame-rows-that-have-max-value-for-named-field)

hello,

I have a data frame like this :

```
   A1 A3    d
1   a pr    5
2   a be    0
3   a cd    8
4   a dy    0
5   b pr    3
6   b be    4
7   b cd    9

etc...
```

I want to test each row, and get the unique rows based on A1 and have max value of d

the output should be like this

```
A1 A3 d
a  cd 8
b  cd 9
```

etc..

The data frame is bigger , but that's an example.

Can this be done with R? without looping and long stuff??

thanks

Comment: @Joris Meys :  it's a duplicate , but i did not understand the whole method used , i was able to generate all ids of the row that have max value , i wasn't able to get a subset of the original data frame based on this id, how this can be done??

Comment: first of all, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/ thoroughly. Second, if you have the ids and you don't know how to subset (see eg ?subset, ?Extract, ...) , it's very much time to start reading any of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r

Comment: @Joris Meys : thanks for your reply. i know how to extract them , but i needed another way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to sort the `d` column, and them remove duplicates in the `A1` column:

```
df2 <- df[order(df$d,decreasing=T),]
df2[!duplicated(df2$A1),]
```

This does assume that there is a single unique maximum, you would lose some results if there were more than 1.

Comment: thanks alot , it worked :) , but i think there is more than 1 maximum value in each column , but i only need 1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
ddply(dfr, "A1", function(curdfr){curdfr[which.max(curdfr$d),]})
```

Comment: Note: I haven't tested this as there wasn't proper example data provided (as in: easy to test with, without having to resort to textconnection and the like; read: `dput`.)

Comment: +1 for comments that take long to type than to create sample data!

Answer (score 0):

DATA

```
mydf <- read.table(textConnection("
 Lp   A1 A3    d
 1   a pr    5
 2   a be    0
 3   a cd    8
 4   a dy    0
 5   b pr    3
 6   b be    4
 7   b cd    9"),header=T,row.names="Lp")
```

CODE

```
require(data.table)
mydf <- data.table(mydf)
mydf[,.SD[which.max(d)],by=A1]
```